# Permanent Resident as Family member of European citizen

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens, spouses, italian-residents

I'm a Filipina with permanent residency as a family member of European national (Article 20) given by the Italian authorities. I have a Philippine passport and I'm married to a British national; we're living in Italy due to work.

Do I need to apply for a visa to travel to the UK alone, even for a short stay (4 days)?

Answer (score 2):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ph&DE=gb&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=it&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a "Permanent
>   Residence Card of a Family Member of a Union Citizen" or a
>    Residence Card of a Family Member of a Union Citizen  issued
>   by Italy to family members of a national of
>     Switzerland or an EEA Member State. **They must
>     travel with or travel to join the national of Switzerland or
>     EEA Member State.**

So if he's not going to be in the UK while you're there, you **do** need a visa.